# Get versionID while using quertText

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am executing rest query using queryText for content search which I was able to get and even the all the required metadata but I was able to get the versionID of particular file. Is there is option to get VersionID while doing queryText.

Below is the query i am using

```
https://xxx.sharepoint.com//sites/abc/_api/search/query?querytext='abc'&rowLimit=200&trimduplicates=false&selectProperties='Filename,ListItemId'
```

Answer (score 0):

The property you are looking for is

```
'IsCurrentVersion'
```

Unlike the name would suggest it won't give you a true/false value but the current version of a document. For exaple 1.2

Not sure but i guess it should work in your case. I use it in queries via 'sp-pnp-js' library

Comment: Hi @MP_89 thanks for the answer but IsCurrentVersion is working on normal Rest Query not with querytext which is relate to managed property. And I am looking VersionID(which willl be like 512, 1028, 1536) not VersionLabel. Kindly update if you have any idea on same

Comment: Hey @suresh thanks for that information. I didn't know that. Sorry that my answer won't help you any further

Comment: thanks for sharing your idea